# Pass value to an include file in php

Tags: php

How do you pass a parameter into an include file? I tried the following but it doesn't work.

include "myfile.php?var=123";

and in myfile.php, I try to retrieve the parameter using $_GET["var"].

`include "myfile.php?var=123";` will not work. PHP searches for a file with this exact name and does not parse the parameter

for that I also did this:

`include "http://MyGreatSite.com/myfile.php?var=123";`but it does not also work.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Afaik you cannot include remote files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the contents of the included file in a function (or functions). That way you can just do

```
include "myfile.php";
myFileFunction($var1, $var2);
```

Answer (score 6):

quick and dirty

```
 $var = 123;
 include "myfile.php";
```

in myfile just use "$var"

The same but without global variables:

```
  function use_my_file($param) {
      $var = $param;
      include "myfile.php";
  }
```

Hold on, are you trying to include the *result* of myfile.php, not its php code? Consider the following then

```
  $var = 123;
  readfile("http://MyGreatSite.com/myfile.php?var=$var"); //requires allow_url_fopen=on in php.ini
```

[virtual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) might also work

Comment: I was just about to type that :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a function, that's what they are for:

#### included.php

```
<?php

function doFoo($param) {
    // do something with $param
}
```

#### file.php

```
<?php

require_once 'included.php';

doFoo('some argument');
```

Answer (score 1):

Code in included files is executed in the same scope as the including file.

This:

```
// main.php
$var = 'a';
include 'inc.php';
echo $var;

// inc.php
$var = 'b';
```

Is for most intents and purposes exactly the same as:

```
// main.php
$var = 'a';
$var = 'b';
echo $var;
```