# calling php file fron another php file while passing arguments

Tags: php

i need to call a php inside another php file and pass some arguments also. how can i do this??
i tried

```
include("http://.../myfile.php?file=$name");
```

- but gives access denied. i read like v must not set allow_url_open to OFF.

if i write like

```
$cmd = "/.../myfile.php?file=".$name";
$out =exec($cmd. " 2>&1");
echo $out;
```

- gives error as /.../myfiles.php?file=hello: no such file or directory.

how can i solve this???

Comment: What exactly do you need to do. Fetch a block of PHP for execution inside the current script, or run an external script with no connection to the current script?

Comment: use `curl` and make `allow_url_open` ON

Comment: does this php file located on the same server?

Comment: i got the answer....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644199/pass-value-to-an-include-file-in-php

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have to pass anything in to your included files, your variables from the calling document will be available by default;

File1.php

```
<?php

$variable = "Woot!";
include "File2.php"; //if in the same folder
```

File2.php

```
<?php
echo $variable;
```

Comment: That's right, basically php just appends the documents so any variable declared before will be also available

Comment: this syntex to include file worked for me not above.

include("insert_DB.php");

Comment: It should be 
`include "File2.php";`

Answer (score 1):

the location in your code is incorrect:

```
$cmd = "/.../myfile.php?file=".$name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can include file over http only if the **allow_url_fopen** is set to TRUE, and the same parameter allow you to pass variables to the files...

Answer (score 0):

You should not include files via HTTP connection - that's almost always a serious security problem.

If you must do this, you have to set `allow_url_include` **and** `allow_url_fopen` to `ON` but neither is a recommended procedure.