# pass variable in file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I want pass some variable in file_get_contents() function.

```
  <?php
  extract($_POST);
  $html_content= file_get_contents("counties/indrsen/1.php");
  $tenant_html=$first_name.' '.$last_name."_$new.html";
  file_put_contents("3_day_notice_fad/$tenant_html",$html_content);
   ?>
```

Where **1.php** is simple php file, save in **counties/indrsen**. From above code I call 1.php and want save html file in other folder, name is **3_day_notice_fad** with variables. It is saving successfully in folder, but when I open html file, it is not showing with variable name.

I want to pass variable **$first_name** and **$last_name** in **file_put_contents("3_day_notice_fad/$tenant_html",$html_content);**

1.php is below:

```
<p>To: Tenant's Name: <?php echo "$first_name.' '.$last_name"; ?> </p>
```

It shows html page like 

To: Tenant's Name:

But I want value it with values like like 

To: Tenant's Name: xyx jjj

Comment: `eval` perhaps - but be careful

Comment: `file_get_contents` is __not__ a template engine. Neither does it _run_ your php-code.

Comment: Rename your .html to .php otherwise the vars are never going to compile. You also need to declare the vars inside the new page.

Comment: you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644199/pass-value-to-an-include-file-in-php

Comment: where is `(_)$new` defined? Or are you wanting to write that variable in a file? and the POST origins are unknown and their value(s). The question is unclear.

Comment: Variables are extracting from POST and I want to pass variables in file_get_contents() and should be save in newly generated html file through  file_put_contents()

Comment: Can any one please connect with team viewer, so that I can show properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for reply. I found my answer by

```
    ob_start();
    include('counties/indrsen/1.php');
    $html_content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Its working fine.

Comment: Nice. Thx for this.